# Python-Need to turn this into a loop so it look like my picture?

Tags: python, loops

I need to write this program using a loop

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gko6T.jpg

this is what i have so far but my program has to look exactly and the picture???

```
def main():

    sum=0.0
    for i in range(1,6):
        x,y=eval(input("Please enter length and width of room:"))
        sf=(x*y)
        sum=sum+sf
        print("The total square footage is",sum)

main()
```

Thank you for your help...

Comment: You've made a goo start, but you haven't actually asked a question here.  What are you having trouble with?  Please read the [FAQ] and [ask] for more details on how to post here.

Comment: "I need to write this program using a loop"

Comment: I need to know how to get the room number in my input to change in the loop as in the pic, room 1 to 5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just drop the indent on the print statement.

```
sum=0.0
for i in range(1,6):
    x,y=eval(input("Please enter length and width of room:"))
    sf=(x*y)
    sum=sum+sf
print("The total square footage is",sum)
```

**edited:**

This is a common technique in python you could use to achieve what you want:

```
sum=0.0
for i in range(1,6):
    x,y=eval(input("Please enter length and width of room %i:" % i ))
    sf=(x*y)
    sum=sum+sf
print("The total square footage is %i" % sum )
```

What i'm doing here is placing a wildcard in the middle of the string and then pass the parameters. '%i' tells the % operator that you are going to insert an integer. You can also put '%s' if you were going to add a string. There are a couple more you can check out. This is another example for the console:

```
>>> user_name = 'mauricio'
>>> sum = 42
>>> line_to_print = 'Hello user %s, your sum is %i' % (user_name, sum)
>>> print(line_to_print)
Hello mauricio, your sum is 42
```

Comment: Thank you so much, one more thing do u know how to make my input question have the room number like in the pic it shows room 1 then room 2 an so on in the loop???